# Memset for Unique Pointers

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I am converting a C code to C++.

There is matrix pointer:

```
MATRIX* matrix = NULL;
matrix = new MATRIX[256];

if (matrix == NULL)
   return FAIL;
memset(matrix, 0, 256*sizeof(MATRIX));
```

Then it was filled on a different method:

```
fillUpMatrix(matrix);
```

And in fillUpMatrix():

```
memcpy(&matrix[start], &someOtherMatrix[pos], sizeof(MATRIX));
```

And later on memset was called for the pointer since it will be filled with a different set of values:

```
memset(matrix, 0, 256*sizeof(MATRIX));
```

---

So what I did was:

```
auto matrix= std::make_unique<MATRIX[]>(256);
fillUpMatrix(matrix.get());
```

I skipped the first `memset` since I believe I do not need it anymore for smart pointers.
But the second `memset` I believe is needed (since new values will be saved). So how do I write that in C++ and considering that I am using a smart pointer?  Is my conversion above correct?

Comment: Was there any reason to use `make_unique<MATRIX[]>` instead of `vector<MATRIX>`? The answer to this might affect the answer to your question.

Comment: I also think using `std::vector<Matrix>` would help; then you can use std::copy etc without worrying of `sizeof(Matrix)`

Comment: Hmm my thought was since it was ```MATRIX* matrix = NULL;``` then I should use a smart pointer. And if ```MATRIX matrix``` then I will use a ```vector```. Is that incorrect? And should I just use a vector? If I really have to use ```make_unique```, any suggestions?

Comment: yes that is incorrect, vector does store its elements on the heap so it is the perfect replacement for `MATRIX* matrix`, for stack allocated elements the equivalent would be `std::array`

Comment: `memset()` will have undefined behaviour if `MATRIX` is not a trivially copyable type.   That excludes, among other things, having any non-trivial constructor, a non-trivial destructor, any virtual functions, or any virtual bases.   For more information, have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable

Comment: Consider using `std::vector` or `std::array` instead.

Comment: afaik `std::make_unique<MATRIX[]>(256);` is for when you cannot use `std;:vector` for some reason, when you can you should use it

Comment: Forget about `memset`. You don't need it. Ever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I skipped the first `memset` since I believe I do not need it anymore for smart pointers.

You're right that it isn't needed, but the reason for not needing it specifically that you used `std::make_unique`, which value initialises the array; not because you're using smart pointers. That is assuming initialisation is needed in the first place. That doesn't appear to be the case, since the content is about to be filled in a function.

Do take into consideration that `std::memset` and `std::memcpy` behave correctly only if the type (`Matrix` in this case) is trivially copyable. If that is not the case, you must use `std::fill_n` (or `std::fill`) and `std::copy` respectively. Which can be used if the type is trivially copyable too, so you might as well use them in any case.

> But the second memset I believe is needed (since new values will be saved).

Similar to the first `std::memset`, It's unclear why you think that a second `std::memset` is needed (whether in C or C++). If the new values are going to be written over the array, then what effect does the `std::memset` have?

> So how do I write that in C++ and considering that I am using a smart pointer?

You can `std::memset` an array pointed by smart pointer like this:

```
std::memset(matrix.get(), 0, 256*sizeof(decltype(*matrix)));
```

Or using `std::fill_n` instead:

```
std::fill_n(matrix.get(), 256, MATRIX{});
```

> Hmm my thought was since it was `MATRIX* matrix = NULL;` then I should use a smart pointer.

`std::vector` is a RAII container that represents a dynamic array. You're dynamically allocating an array. `std::vector` is appropriate.

Converting C to C++ is not just about replacing bare owning pointers with smart pointers. Another thing to do is to replace custom re-implementations of typical data structures and algorithms with the standard ones provided by the standard library.

Comment: Thank you! This clarifies a lot of things for me. Thank you!

Comment: I think `std::fill_n` is better alternative in such situations.

Answer (score 1):

- Using a `vector<MATRIX>` would solve many problems.
- `new` doesn't return null, but throws. Hence null check has no effect (unless `nothrow` is used).
- You're mixing raw pointer approach with newer smart-pointer, vector based approach. You shouldn't be using any raw memory manipulation functions in the latest C++ code.
- Instead, have a constructor in the `MATRIX` class which would initialize all members of `MATRIX`. You can have (or *prevent*) copy/move constructors/assignment operators. Consider using `=default` and `=delete` with special member functions.
- `memcpy` etc may corrupt the state of some non-POD members in `MATRIX` type (like `std::string`, `std::vector`). Such undefined-behaviours are hard to detect, hence don't use any mem* functions.

Comment: it is not just "may corrupt" but afaik it is UB

Comment: Yes. I just kept it simple.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Just in case I cannot use a vector, any other suggestion how to make the ```memset``` to ```0``` into C++ code? I am only allowed to change this portion of the code so I am not sure if I can change the MATRIX class at all.

Comment: If `memset` to MATRIX is called/used at many places, then I'd suggest having a helper function. Let's say `ResetMatrix(MATRIX&)` which would call memset of any other function. You can improve this function, put runtime assertions, write unit test on top of it etc.